# How to instantiate std::exception_ptr for unit testing purpose

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I have the system that runs asynchronous network worker and periodically checks if the worker has some `std::exception_ptr` stored. In this case it might throw, or report an error in some other way. Simple example:

```
#include <exception>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

// simplified Network interface and the mock
struct INetwork {
    virtual std::exception_ptr getExceptionPtr() const = 0;
};
struct MockedNetwork: public INetwork {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(std::exception_ptr, getExceptionPtr, (), (const override));
};
// simplified system
class System {
public:
    System(INetwork& network): _network{network} {}
    void run() {
        // some complex logic
        std::exception_ptr exPtr = _network.getExceptionPtr();
        if (exPtr) {
            // error handling, or just rethrow
            std::rethrow_exception(exPtr);
        }
    }
private:
    INetwork& _network;
};
```

Then I would like to test my code for the following scenario

> Whenever Network reports an error through exception_ptr, System shall rethrow this exception

so I have this small gtest testcase:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct MyException: public std::runtime_error {
    MyException(): std::runtime_error("MyException") {}
};

TEST(Demo, demo) {
    MockedNetwork mockedNet;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedNet, getExceptionPtr()).WillRepeatedly([]() -> std::exception_ptr{
        return nullptr;  // this is OK, but I want to simulate an error, not error-free run
        // return new MyException;  // this doesn't compile, and anyway seems like a bad idea
    });
    System sut(mockedNet);
    ASSERT_THROW(sut.run(), MyException);
}
```

How can I simulate the situation where my mocked network returns `std::exception_ptr` containing a pointer to my custom exception that can be rethrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::make_exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/make_exception_ptr):

```
std::exception_ptr e = std::make_exception_ptr(MyException{});
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how could I not have seen it in cppreference ... Now I feel stupid. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be quite simple. In the test setup you can just throw an exception inside the `try` block, then catch it, store the `std::exception_ptr`, and use it in the gmock action:

```
TEST(Demo, demo) {
    MockedNetwork mockedNet;
    std::exception_ptr ptr;
    try {
        throw MyException();
    } catch(const std::exception&) {
        ptr = std::current_exception();
    }
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedNet, getExceptionPtr()).WillRepeatedly([ptr]() -> std::exception_ptr{
        return ptr;
    });
    System sut(mockedNet);
    ASSERT_THROW(sut.run(), MyException);
}
```

This works, but maybe there are other better and/or more interesting ways to achieve the same effect.